# CSS Vertical align does not work

Tags: html, css

I've got what I think to be quite an interesting problem. Whenever I try to vertical-align all the elements I need - it won't work, but if I leave one out, it appears to work.
Here's the code:

```
<body style='margin:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#e8e7e7'>
  <div id='holder' style='width:100%; height:100%; margin:0'>
    <div id='blackout' style='width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#000; opacity:0.5; position:absolute; z-index:1'></div>
    <div id='data_holder' style='width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2; position:relative; text-align:center'>
      <div id='geo' style='width:96.9%; height:40%; background-color:#9F6; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle'></div>
      <div id='dis_v' style='width:24%; height:25%; background-color:#9F6; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle'></div>
      <div id='dis_d' style='width:24%; height:25%; background-color:#9F6; display:inline-block; '></div>
      <div id='dis_b' style='width:24%; height:25%; background-color:#9F6; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle'></div>
      <div id='dis_o' style='width:24%; height:25%; background-color:#9F6; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle'></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to know what's causing this problem and how can I solve it and vertical-align all the elements inside the data holder div.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mw5Tv/1/) of the problem.

Comment: Hmm... seems to work for me on Firefox 30, what browser are you using?

Comment: @ced-b Using Chrome 35.0.1916.153 (latest)

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle for the exact problem? I cannot seem to replicate this.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast added a jsFiddle

Comment: works fine w/ current ff and chrome

Comment: The elements that have vertical-align. What do you think they are being aligned with?

Comment: @Alohci Well they should align with their parent element, shouldn't they?

Comment: What is the layout suppose to look like?

Comment: No. They align with the line-box they are in. Which effectively means the other elements inside data_holder. So if they all have vertical-align:middle and are the same height, they'll all form a straight line. Which they do. The height of the parent element plays no part in that alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key idea that you're missing is that you need to set line-height in data_holder. That's just how vertical-align works. (You'll need to use a height like 200px rather than 100%.) See this question for better info:

[How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Comment: Could you please add a jsFiddle? I've tried what you said but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) work just for text. I usually use margin/padding for vertical align. And add your code to a playground.

Comment: please don't ever refer to w3schools;
afaik valign works for inline parent elements